# What are good ways to sign up Apple Developer Program without using my legal name?

Tags: app-store-connect

Let's say a man named **San Zhang (张三)**, a citizen of China. He may be living in China or The US. He has a English name **"John Smith"**, which he wants to use as the "seller name" of his apps on App Store.

However, when he tried signing up Apple Developer Program, he was told that the "seller name" will be same to the name on credit card, which will be used to pay for the program fee and receive payment for apps he sold.

Now, the problem is:

1. China government doesn't let him use **John Smith** as legal name.
2. China government doesn't allow him to use a name different from **张三** when opening a bank account.
3. The US government doesn't allow him to use a name different from **San Zhang** when opening a bank account. *(Not sure this one)*
4. He cannot migrate to the US before the planned release date of his first Mac/iOS app. Or he doesn't want to become a citizen of a country where he is allowed to use **John Smith** as legal name.

In such a case, could he use **John Smith** as "seller name" of his apps on App Store? Or he has to open a company to sell apps? (In other words, could he achieve this goal, which seems not being allowed/expected/supposed by Apple?)

Another case is, could a US citizen use another name than his legal name as "seller name" on App Store?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use your Chinese name. Why would you like to use your English name?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a support phone number as well as email to assist with developer account creation. I would suggest you simply obey the rules that Apple has established for their account creation as best you can and then contact the developer support team if you are prevented from signing up or want to ensure you will be paid properly once the release date draws near.

You may also want to get legal advice in the country which your Apple ID is based when you register it. You probably won't need it for something as simple as translation of names, but part of your question seems to imply legal concerns and getting that sort of advice from the internet would be a waste of your time since Lawyers don't give advice over the internet in general due to professional obligations to ensure they actually represent a specific client properly.